# Flickering screen in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I still can't find an answer to my specific problem. I have attached a photo:

[image]

As you can see, the flashes go behind the items that I'm holding which is a bit weird, and to me, means it is not a problem with the actual laptop, and maybe it's a problem with the actual application itself. They happen at random and seem to reflect whatever environment I'm in; if I'm in the nether, the flashes are red, if I'm in a cave, they're grey. Note that my laptop isn't a gaming laptop, but it's still relatively high-end and should be able to take some light gaming. I have also tried to adjust the video setting on Minecraft itself to no avail.

- No mods, all vanilla, not even a texture pack
- It's most prominent on servers. Don't know if it's exclusive to servers, need more testing
- No modifications have been made to my laptop itself
- Drivers + Windows are updated fully, recently updated BIOS but this problem seemed to happen even before then
- To my memory, this has happened since I got the game. Been more prominent lately though as I've been playing a lot more

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any mods installed that could cause this? Any modifications to the client could cause undefined behavior.
It also could be caused by limits of low-end video memory or display driver corruption in general. Please update your display drivers and restart your computer. Also you should mention the things you have done prior to the issue.